# I can't run the first example in the awk manual?

Tags: awk

The awk manual lists this as one of the first examples:

```
awk "BEGIN { print \"Don't Panic!\" }"
```

Apparently I should see "Don't Panic!", but actually I see:

```
-bash: !\": event not found
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on your shell.

```
> bash
$ awk "BEGIN { print \"Don't Panic!\" }"
bash: !\": event not found
$ tcsh
> awk "BEGIN { print \"Don't Panic!\" }"
Unmatched '.
> sh
$ awk "BEGIN { print \"Don't Panic!\" }"
Don't Panic!
$
```

Exclamation points are used by modern shells to refer to parts of your command line history.  In `bash` and `tcsh`, they can be interpreted as a history reference.  You can escape the `!` with a `\`, or you can leave it out, or you can use a simple shell.

In my `bash` example above, you see thie failed history substitution.  In my `tcsh` example, you see a problem with quoting (since double quotes can't be escaped this way).  The awk manual you're using is presumably old enough that it doesn't assume everyone runs bash.

Comment: On a side note, you can disable history expansion with `set +H` in `bash`.

Comment: Ah, good point.  And on another side note, this kind of history expansion problem is only applicable to interactive shells; there are no history events inside scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
awk "BEGIN { print \"Don't Panic\!\" }"
```

This should do the trick (under zsh).

Comment: Great - that worked! ( but I got `warning: escape sequence `\!' treated as plain `!' )

Comment: Have a look at http://objectmix.com/awk/504942-gawk-regexp-warning-message.html :-)